# SQL Server Maximum Stored Procedure Limit issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, oledb

I'm getting the following error after creating a trigger in SQL Server, i have researched this error and tried so many different things but nothing has worked.

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e14'  Maximum
>   stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded
>   (limit 32)

```
USE [admin_W4F]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [lee2121].[discount]    Script Date: 6/7/2019     10:45:55 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [lee2121].[discount]
ON  [lee2121].[Cart]
AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

update [lee2121].Cart
set totalprice2 = [lee2121].[Cart].[price] - ([lee2121].[Cart]. [price]/[lee2121].[Cart].[disc])

END
```

Comment: It seems you may have the `RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS` database option set so the update invokes the trigger again. Also your `UPDATE` is updating every row in the table each time it is fired.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a trigger for this!  Just use a computed column:

```
alter table [lee2121].[Cart]
    add totalprice2 (price - (price / disc);
```

The value will be calculated when the table is queried.  The values will always be up-to-date.

Comment: Computed column sounds like a good option, i entered your code but it did not like it so I'm going to do some research into computed columns and try and work out how to code the formula, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your trigger is firing your trigger? Try adding NOT FOR REPLICATION

Answer (score 0):

so in the end i have gone with a computed column which seems to be working fine, i used this code;

([price]-[price]/[disc])

Thank you.